# No notification of receiving call whilst on a call

Tags: ios, iphone

While on a call, any other calls do not come in. After the end of the first call, I do not get any notification that I have missed a call. I have turned off call waiting but this has not helped.

Answer (score 2):

This is something your carrier must support. Contact your carrier.